# Node.js: Difference between req.query[] and req.params

Tags: node.js, query-string

Is there a difference between obtaining QUERY_STRING arguments via `req.query[myParam]` and `req.params.myParam`? If so, when should I use which?

Answer (score 201, accepted):

[`req.params`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params) contains route parameters (in the path portion of the URL), and [`req.query`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query) contains the URL query parameters (after the `?` in the URL).

You can also use [`req.param(name)`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.param) to look up a parameter in both places (as well as `req.body`), but this method is now deprecated.

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks, so both is provided by Express.
And POST data I access via req.body.myParam?

Comment: Right.  Which one to use depends upon what you're trying to do.

Comment: Also note: "Direct access to req.body, req.params, and req.query should be favoured for clarity - unless you truly accept input from each object." - express documentation

Comment: `req.param` is now deprecated. Node suggests using `req.query` or `req.params`

Comment: why deprecate it? what if we use params or query and then decide to change it to another?

Comment: @JohnnyHK can we use request.body instead of req.query or param as it is dreprecated?

Answer (score 371):

Given this route

```
app.get('/hi/:param1', function(req,res){} );
// regex version
app.get(/^\/hi\/(.*)$/, function(req,res){} );
// unnamed wild card
app.get('/hi/*', function(req,res){} );
```

and given this URL
`http://www.google.com/hi/there?qs1=you&qs2=tube`

You will have:

req.**query**

```
{
  qs1: 'you',
  qs2: 'tube'
}
```

req.**params**

```
{
  param1: 'there'
}
```

> When you use a regular expression for the route definition, capture groups are provided in the array using `req.params[n]`, where n is the nth capture group. This rule is applied to unnamed wild card matches with string routes

[Express req.params >>](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params)

Comment: What if i need to get /hi/ ?

Comment: take a look at req.url or req.originalUrl or req._originalUrl, then split on the `/`

Comment: this should be the answer, clean and clear, easy to get the idea,

Answer (score 84):

### request.params

Suppose you have defined your route name like this:

```
https://localhost:3000/user/:userId
```

which will become:

```
https://localhost:3000/user/5896544
```

Here, if you will print:
**request.params**

```
{
userId : 5896544
}
```

so

```
request.params.userId = 5896544
```

so **request.params** is an object containing properties to the named route

---

### request.query

The **request.query** comes from query parameters in the URL
eg:

```
https://localhost:3000/user?userId=5896544
```

**request.query**

```
{

userId: 5896544

}
```

so

```
request.query.userId = 5896544
```

Comment: Good explanation

Comment: Well explained!

Answer (score 9):

You should be able to access the query using dot notation now.

If you want to access say you are receiving a **GET** request at `/checkEmail?type=email&utm_source=xxxx&email=xxxxx&utm_campaign=XX` and you want to fetch out the *query* used.

```
var type = req.query.type,
    email = req.query.email,
    utm = {
     source: req.query.utm_source,
     campaign: req.query.utm_campaign
    };
```

**Params** are used for the self defined parameter for receiving request, something like (example):

```
router.get('/:userID/food/edit/:foodID', function(req, res){
 //sample GET request at '/xavg234/food/edit/jb3552'

 var userToFind = req.params.userID;//gets xavg234
 var foodToSearch = req.params.foodID;//gets jb3552
 User.findOne({'userid':userToFind}) //dummy code
     .then(function(user){...})
     .catch(function(err){console.log(err)});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to mention one important note regarding `req.query` , because currently I am working on pagination functionality based on `req.query` and I have one interesting example to demonstrate to you...

Example:

```
// Fetching patients from the database
exports.getPatients = (req, res, next) => {

const pageSize = +req.query.pageSize;
const currentPage = +req.query.currentPage;

const patientQuery = Patient.find();
let fetchedPatients;

// If pageSize and currentPage are not undefined (if they are both set and contain valid values)
if(pageSize && currentPage) {
    /**
     * Construct two different queries 
     * - Fetch all patients 
     * - Adjusted one to only fetch a selected slice of patients for a given page
     */
    patientQuery
        /**
         * This means I will not retrieve all patients I find, but I will skip the first "n" patients
         * For example, if I am on page 2, then I want to skip all patients that were displayed on page 1,
         * 
         * Another example: if I am displaying 7 patients per page , I want to skip 7 items because I am on page 2,
         * so I want to skip (7 * (2 - 1)) => 7 items
         */
        .skip(pageSize * (currentPage - 1))

        /**
         * Narrow dont the amound documents I retreive for the current page
         * Limits the amount of returned documents
         * 
         * For example: If I got 7 items per page, then I want to limit the query to only
         * return 7 items. 
         */
        .limit(pageSize);
}
patientQuery.then(documents => {
    res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Patients fetched successfully',
        patients: documents
    });
  });
};
```

You will noticed `+` sign in front of `req.query.pageSize` and `req.query.currentPage`

Why? If you delete `+` in this case, you will get an error, and that error will be thrown because we will use invalid type (with error message 'limit' field must be numeric).

**Important**: By default if you extracting something from these query parameters, it will **always be a string**, because it's coming the URL and it's treated as a text.

If we need to work with numbers, and convert query statements from text to number, we can simply add a plus sign in front of statement.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add that if you're coming from `axios`, (GET/POST) you make `query/url params` (readable with `req.query`) available via the config:

```js
axios.post('/users', {...data}, {
  headers: {...anyHeaders},
  params: {uid: `${uid}`}
})
```

And you make `path/route variables` (readable with `req.params`) available via the path:

```js
axios.get(`/users/${uid`}, {
  headers: {...anyHeaders}
})
```

Let me also add this, the names used to read query params on the server must match those from the client. This is not the case with path variables where any name can be used on the server, provided that portion of the path/route is available (basically does a substitution - kinda like how `react-router` does it: `/path/:variable`).