# how to extract URL parameter from POST request in nodejs and expressjs

Tags: ajax, node.js, post, express

REQUEST URL http://localhost:9090/rest-api/fetchDetailedProductInfo?prodId=1&tempId=123

```
fetchDetailedProductInfo: function (prodId) {                                      
    var self = this;
    var URL = 'http://localhost:9090/rest-api/fetchDetailedProductInfo'
    $.ajax({                                               
        url: URL,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType:'json',
        type:'GET',
        data: {
            'prodId':prodId,
            'tempId':123
        },                       
        success:function(responce) {
            self.renderUI(responce.json);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log('ERROR',err)
        }
    });                    
},
```

@ SERVER SIDE

```
router.get('/rest-api/fetchDetailedProductInfo', function (req, res) {  
    var prodId = req.param('prodId');
    var tempId = req.param('tempId');
    res.send(prodId + '----' + tempId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you confused with req.params and req.query. Here is link to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417592/node-js-difference-between-req-query-and-req-params)

Use req.query

```
 var prodId = req.query.prodId;
 var tempId = req.query.tempId;
```

Please [see this](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.query)