# Search feature using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I am creating an application using mean stack. I need to create a advanced search feature for my application where schema can searched by various fields like firstname, lastname, etc. On clicking the search button I will use the below route to connect to the server.

```
$http.get('/search/' + $routeParams.searchdata)
```

now if I try to console log the searchdata I can get the fields that I entered in the search form. Eg: If I enter the first name and the email id I see in the console as

**{"firstname": "Smith", "email": "smith@gmail.com"}**

If I try to access **searchdata.firstname** I get **undefined**.

1) How can I access the fields entered in the search form?

2) There are many fields in the schema. How will I tell to search only the fields that were entered in the form?

Answer (score 0):

> 1) How can I access the fields entered in the search form?

See this answer [Node.js: Difference between req.query[] and req.params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417592/node-js-difference-between-req-query-and-req-params?answertab=votes#tab-top)

> ```
> 2) There are many fields in the schema. How will I tell to search only the fields that were entered in the form?
> ```

Just pass the query to your find mongoose function like this :

```
app.get('yourPath', function(req, res){
    yourCollection.find(req.query, function(err, elements){
                if(err)
                       res.status(500).send(err);
                else{
                               res.json(elements);
                }
}
```