# Retrieve query string parameters in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, url-parameters, restify

I am trying to retrieve query string parameters from a URL. I am using node.js restify module.

The URL looks like this;

http://127.0.0.1:7779/echo?UID=Trans001&FacebookID=ae67ea324&GetDetailType=FULL

The extracted relevant code;

```
server.use(restify.bodyParser());

server.listen(7779, function () {
    console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});

server.get('/echo/:message', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("req.params.UID:" + req.params.UID);
    console.log("req.params.FacebookID:" + req.params.FacebookID);
    console.log("req.params.GetDetailType" + req.params.GetDetailType);

    var customers = [
        {name: 'Felix Jones', gender: 'M'},
        {name: 'Sam Wilson', gender: 'M'},
    ];
    res.send(200, customers);

    return next();
});
```

How can the code be modified so that `req.params.UID` and the other parameters can be retrieved from the URL http://127.0.0.1:7779/echo?UID=Trans001&FacebookID=ae67ea324&GetDetailType=FULL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `req.query`instead of `req.params`. You can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417592/node-js-difference-between-req-query-and-req-params)

```
server.use(restify.bodyParser());
server.use(restify.queryParser());

server.listen(7779, function () {
    console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});

server.get('/echo', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("req.query.UID:" + req.query.UID);
    console.log("req.query.FacebookID:" + req.query.FacebookID);
    console.log("req.query.GetDetailType" + req.query.GetDetailType);

    var customers = [
        {name: 'Felix Jones', gender: 'M'},
        {name: 'Sam Wilson', gender: 'M'},
    ];
    res.send(200, customers);

    return next();
});
```

Comment: Upvoted. Answer is almost correct. It works if the URL is http://127.0.0.1:7779/echo/?UID=Trans001&FacebookID=ae67ea324&GetDetailType=FULL  

It does not work when URL is http://127.0.0.1:7779/echo?UID=Trans001&FacebookID=ae67ea324&GetDetailType=FULL

Note the slight difference in the `echo` part of the URL.

Comment: I edited minor part of your answer so that it is completely correct. Please accept the edit. THanks.