# How to match Array elements in Sub-Documents by Criteria

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have following Mongoose schemas :

**EmployeeSchema :**

```
var EmployeeSchema = new Schema({
    name : String,
    employeeDetailsId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'employeedetails'
    }
});
```

**EmployeeDetailSchema :**

```
var EmployeeDetailSchema = new Schema({
    employeeId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'employee'
    },
    primarySkills: [
    {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'skills'
    }
],
});
```

**SkillsSchema :**

```
var SkillsSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});
```

`EmployeeDetailSchema` data gets saved on demand, like when a particular Skill is assigned to Employee. Once `EmployeeDetail` document is saved then corresponding `EmployeeDetailID` is saved back to `EmployeeSchema` as `employeeDetailsId`.

Now there is bi-directional relationship between `EmployeeSchema` and `EmployeeDetailSchema`.

**NOTE :**
Multiple Skills can be associated to an Employee and they are stored as an array of ObjectID's in EmployeeDetails Schema.

**UseCase :**

I want to fetch all Employees who have particular Skill associated with them, Skill will be input to the Mongoose / Mongo query.

Say input Skill ID is 1234 then i want to fetch all employees who have Skill id 1234 in EmployeeDetail > PrimarySkills array.

Following is the approach which i tried using Mongoose :

```
EmployeeModel.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'employeedetails', 
            localField: 'employeeDetailsId',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'details'
        }
    },
    {
        $match: { 
            $and: [
                { "details.primarySkills": { "$exists": true } },               
                { 
                    "details.primarySkills": { 
                        $in: [mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.skillId)]                          
                    }
                }
            ]
        } 
    }
]).exec(function (err, result) {
    if (err) return res.send('400', {
        message: 'Unable to fetch employees data by status. Please try again later'
     });

     return res.jsonp(result);
});
```

**Result** : Empty array.

I have no clue where am going wrong, need some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad, original approach which i followed was all fine except a small mistake. I should have used `req.query.skillId` instead of `req.params.skillId`

For those wondering the difference b/w query and params, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417592/node-js-difference-between-req-query-and-req-params/#answer-14508182)

This is the final solution, thought it may help others :

```
EmployeeModel.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'employeedetails', 
            localField: 'employeeDetailsId',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'details'
        }
    },
    {
        $match: { 
            $and: [
                { "details.primarySkills": { "$exists": true } },               
                { 
                    "details.primarySkills": { 
                        $in: [mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.query.skillId)]                          
                    }
                }
            ]
        } 
    }
]).exec(function (err, result) {
    if (err) return res.send('400', {
        message: 'Unable to fetch employees data by status. Please try again later'
     });

     return res.jsonp(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach that you could take is apply the [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup) to the `Skills` model on the `EmployeeDetails` model first and then do another lookup to the `Employee` model

```
EmployeeDetails.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "primarySkills": req.query.skillId } },
    { "$unwind": "$primarySkills" }, // skip this pipeline step for MongoDB 3.4 and above
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "skills",// ensure this is the correct collection name
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "localField": "primarySkills",
            "as": "skills"
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$skills" }
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "employeeId": { "$first": "$employeeId" },
            "primarySkills": { "$push": "$skills" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "employees",// ensure this is the correct collection name
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "localField": "employeeId",
            "as": "employee"
        }
    }
]).exec(callback);
```