# How do I query for documents that contain a specific key/value pair

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

Using monogo's shell, 
    `db.collection.find( {key:value} )`
returns exactly what I want, only I want to make this query from a browser using a URL like `localhost:8000/api/profiles?key=value`

I'm trying to use Express, Node and Mongoose.

Here is the code I have:

```
//Get By query route
router.get('/:param', function(req, res){
    var param = req.query(param);
    getProfilebyQuery(function(err, profiles) {
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
res.json(profiles)
    })
});
//METHODS GO HERE
//These methods are stored as variables and called in the Routes above.
//Get by Query
var getProfilebyQuery = function(param, callback) {
    Iprofile.find(param, callback);
};
```

What you can't see is "Iprofile" requires my mongoose schemas. I can't tell what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You don't actually pass the `param` to `getProfilebyQuery`, but `param` is actually undefined as well on the 3rd line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using query parameters ([difference between req.query and req.params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417592/node-js-difference-between-req-query-and-req-params) ), you don't need to define `/:param`. You need to use req.query.

Also you are not passing the `param` variable to function.

```
//Get By query route
router.get('/', function(req, res){
  var param = req.query;
  getProfilebyQuery(param, function(err, profiles) { //pass param
    if(err){
      throw err;
    }
    res.json(profiles)
  })
});
//METHODS GO HERE
//These methods are stored as variables and called in the Routes above.
//Get by Query
var getProfilebyQuery = function(param, callback) {
  Iprofile.find(param, callback);
};
```