# Get wrong parameter from get method in nodejs

Tags: node.js, get

I'm trying to send get method request and want to pass value in URL.

Like my api look like

```
app.get('/api/getlocation/:customerName', customer.getlocation);
```

For call this I wrote in postman

```
localhost:8080/api/getlocation/:customerName=kumbhani
```

For test

```
var customerName = req.params.customerName;
console.log('name', customerName); // =kumbhani
```

It returns name with `=` sign - I want only `kumbhani`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colon character in the path in Express has a special meaning: whatever you put in the URL after `getLocation/` will be put in  `req.params.customerName`.

This means in Postman, you should actually call this URL:

```
localhost:8080/api/getlocation/kumbhani
```

→ [See related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417592/node-js-difference-between-req-query-and-req-params).