# ExpressJS res.sendFile causes server to crash on client abort

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, request

Learning NodeJS/ExpressJS here. Below is an example of my extremely simple ExpressJS GET request that is supposed to return a JSON file.

```
app.get("/getFile", async (req, res) => {
  if (res.headersSent) return;

  try {
    res.sendFile(
      path.join(__dirname, "latest-data", "my-file.json"),
      (err) => {
        if (err) {
          res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
        }
      }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.stack);
  }
});
```

While 99.9% of the time the request works as intended. However when stress testing with Apache JMeter to test 1000 concurrent users performing the request, I noticed that when I abort the request, the following error appears and my server process ends.

```
node:_http_outgoing:603
    throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:603:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\my-project\my-project-server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:794:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\my-project\my-project-server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:174:12)
    at C:\Users\USER\Desktop\my-project\my-project-server\index.js:113:27
    at C:\Users\USER\Desktop\my-project\my-project-server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:450:22
    at onaborted (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\my-project\my-project-server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1054:5)
    at onfinish (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\my-project\my-project-server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1088:50)
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:203:9)
    at listener (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\my-project\my-project-server\node_modules\on-finished\index.js:170:15) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
```

Now I can tell that it's something to do with the server trying to send a response more than once, however I cannot seem to understand or figure a way how to avoid or use a try catch statement to avoid my server from crashing. This is an issue that will happen when the server traffic gets heavy, I would like to be able to bypass this.

By applying the following logic at the start `if (res.headersSent) return;` I would assume that it would work but it did not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use BOTH res.sendFile(); and res.send(); in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53757530/how-to-use-both-res-sendfile-and-res-send-in-node-js)

Comment: Which line of code in the code you show is line 113? That's what triggers this error, per the stack trace.  It very well could be that you did get an error from `res.sendFile()`, but the response has already been sent so you can't try to send another one.  If that's the case then you should check `res.headersSent` in your error handler.

Answer (score 0):

Update, seems like the line `res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");` was the cause. Removing it will disallow the server to send a response when it was already attempting a SendFile