# Pass array as query params using Axios and Express router

Tags: express, axios

I have the following axios query

```
axios
      .get(`/api/school/get-pathways-with-partner`, {
        params: { partnerList: e }
      })
```

And my express route is this:

```
router.get(
  `/get-pathways-with-partner/:partnerList`)
```

However, when I hit the router with the query

```
http://localhost:5000/api/school/get-pathways-with-partner?partnerList[]=%7B%22value%22:%22Accenture%22,%22label%22:%22Accenture%22,%22_id%22:%225c9ba397347bb645e0865278%22%7D
```

It gives me a 404, is there something wrong with how i'm defining the route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining your route with a [route parameter](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters), while it looks like you want the params to be regular [query parameters](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query).

That is, instead of reading from `req.params`, you want to read from `req.query`.

So instead of having this route

```js
app.get('/get-pathways-with-partner/:partnerList', (req, res) => {
    let { partnerList } = req.params;
});
```

You should have the following:

```js
app.get('/get-pathways-with-partner/', (req, res) => {
    let { partnerList } = req.query;
});
```

See the stackoverflow post at [**Node.js: Difference between req.query[] and req.params**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14417592/864233) for more information.