# JS searchbox submit not sending values - return undefined or [Object,Object]

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, pug, submit

Why doesn't this form submit send the input values as expected? I am using PUG templating and I can return desired result by doing `http://localhost:3000/search/searchValue` (searchValue being a search string input on the search box) but I can seem to get it to post the data correctly.

I can return results using `http://localhost:3000/search/searchValue` but cant get searchValue to carry through to the controller.

I have tried to edit the controller like this (was returning[object object]) but no luck. What am I missing?

edit I tried in controller to change to string

```
let query = req.params.q;
query = JSON.stringify(query);
result = {email: query} && {fullName: query};
```

I also tried to edit `const query = req.params.q;` to `const query = res.send.q;` which returns JSON repsonse`

and I tried this

```
  const query = req.params.q;
  query = JSON.stringify(query);
  let result = res.send( query );
  result = {email: query} && {fullName: query};
```

---

Original Controller

```js
router.get('/search/:q', (req, res) => {
  const query = req.params.q;
  result = {email: query} && {fullName: query};

  console.log(result);

  Booking.find(result, (err, docs) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.render('results', {
        viewTitle: 'Search Results',
        results: docs,

      });
      console.log(result);
    } else {
      console.log('Error  finding record :' + err);
    }
  });
});
```

layout.pug

```
form.form-inline.my-2.my-lg-0#searchBox(
  method='post'
  action='/search/' +   result
  )
    input.form-control.mr-sm-2(type='text', placeholder='Search', aria-label='Search', id='q' name='q' value=''
            )
    button.btn.btn-outline-success.my-2.my-sm-0(type='submit' id='submit') Search
```

results

```
each doc in results
          -var id = doc._id;
          tr
            td
              a(data-toggle="popover" title="Users ID" data-content= doc._id
              )
                b= doc.fullName
            td= doc.email
            td= doc.mobile
            td= doc.city
            td
```

UPDATE

I edited my code to the following which works when manually entering a url like `http://localhost:3000/search/myquery` , but now I get `http://localhost:3000/search/undefined` and the page is blank with the only query value.

```
router.get('/search/:q', (req, res) => {
const q = req.params.q;
const result = {$or: [{fullName: {$regex: q}}, {email: {$regex: q}}]};
console.log(result);
Booking.find(result, (err, docs) => {
if (!err) {
  res.render('results', {
    viewTitle: 'Search Results',
    results: docs,
  });
  res.sendFile('views/results');
  console.log(query);
} else {
  console.log('Error  finding record :' + err);
}
});
});
router.post('/search/:q', function(req, res) {
const q = req.body.q;
res.send(q);
console.log(q);
});
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to extract the email and full name from the query params then this is wrong `result = {email: query} && {fullName: query};`, also check your declared route url. see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417592/node-js-difference-between-req-query-and-req-params)

or try this:

```
router.get('/search/:q', (req, res) => {
         const { email, fullName } = req.query;
         const q =  req.params.q;
         // do what you need
         const result = {
           email: email,
           fullName: fullName
         }
       });
```

then when calling this route try url like this `'/search/:q?email=bla@bla&fullName=bla'`

Comment: Thank you, for the reply, I am trying to return the results which contain the query within email or fullName fields.

Comment: see above, i add more details