# Express JS url parameter variable issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this user route

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const {
    GetAll,
} = require('../areas/directory/controllers/usercontroller');


router.route('/getall?:username&:email').get(GetAll);


module.exports = router;
```

When I try to access the url in Postman like this: http://localhost:5000/api/user/getall?username=nameone&email=emailone

I get this error: **Cannot GET /api/user/getall**

But, if I change it to

```
router.route('/getall/:username&:email').get(GetAll);
```

and access the url in Postman like this: http://localhost:5000/api/user/getall/username=nameone&email=emailone

it works.

On the other hand, even if it works, I am unable to get the value of my variable.

```
var username = req.params.username;
```

will return username=nameone instead.

Comment: You are confusing _path_ and _query_ parameters.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean? May I know which part of it is incorrect?

Comment: _Your expectations_ are incorrect, the code is working fine. `a=b&c=d` syntax has meaning for _query_ parameters, but you're trying to use it in _path_ parameters where (as you can see) it just gives the whole value of the path segment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `http://localhost:5000/api/user/getall?username=nameone&email=emailone` to work, you should change

```
router.route('/getall?:username&:email').get(GetAll);
```

to

```
"router.route('/getall').get(GetAll);"
```

and use `req.query.username` to access the value of username query parameter and `req.query.email` to access the value of email query parameter.

After making these changes, you can call `http://localhost:5000/api/user/getall?username=nameone&email=emailone` in Postman, you will be able to see the value of `username` and `email` in your code.

This is because you need not have to specify the query parameters in the path, like `?:username` in `router.route('getall')`.

**Edit: adding few more details about path and query**

Please see the top 2 solutions for this question to learn more about path and query and why you should change your code to the way I mentioned above : [here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417592/node-js-difference-between-req-query-and-req-params).

Answer (score 0):

> **Reason for the error...**

Actually the thing what you are trying to do is called **query passing** in the rest api..

But you are trying to access them like **params**

> **sollution**

follow the steps to access the queries

**To pass the data using ? in the api request should be like this you can have multiple query objects

```
http://localhost:5000/getall?email='email'&&password='password'
```

> **Access the query in express app like this**

```
app.post('/getall', (req, res) => {
const {
    email,
    password
} = req.query
return res.status(200).json({
    email,
    password
})

})
```

The **req.query** contains the data you trying to pass throw **?** and then query properties

> **Response of above code would be like this**

```
{
"email": "'email'",
"password": "'password'"
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You should not give query parameters in URL. So, for express the url must be just `/getall` and in your code you access those variables using `req.params.whatever_query_parameter`