# why req.query.patient results undefined node express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am following a tutorial. I matched everything with the tutorial but my code is not working. It is giving undefined output. I couldn't find where is the mistake and why is it happening?

```
app.get("/appointment", async (req,res)=>{
      const patient = req.query.patient;
      console.log(patient);
      const query = { patient: patient };
      // console.log(query)
      const appointments = await appointmentCollection.find(query).toArray();
      res.send(appointments)
    })
```

console.log(patient); giving undefined. and res.send(appointments) give an empty array.
Please help.

Comment: Can you add to the questions how you send the data to the endpoint?

Comment: Actually, I am trying to access data from MongoDB with a specific query using the above code. And when I hit the API console.log(patient); the results are undefined and API returns an empty array on the browser. Please see screenshots in the links  https://prnt.sc/cHilL7YNLgKJ , https://prnt.sc/EBQs-hPJ7Lns

Comment: You are not passing anything as query params in the image. You are just calling endpoint without passing query params. Check this answer to see how to pass query params in the url: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14508182/14389830

Comment: You can see a simple example here : https://hoanguyenit.com/create-login-and-register-using-laravel-8-with-react.html

Comment: In react, you can add data to FormData or json, Nodejs using bodyparser : https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Comment: When I pass query then it returns values https://prnt.sc/mMzbJFJvwbup
When I am trying to access it from the client end it returns nothing https://prnt.sc/BZ_g_XRhMju_
My client end code https://prnt.sc/BtO098eTxMig

Answer (score 0):

In your screenshots, you access it as `localhost:5000/appointments`. `req.query.patient` looks for `?patient=yourvaluehere` after your endpoint, being for example,

`localhost:5000/appointments?patient=value`

This should now work as a request query. If `res.send()` sends nothing back, but `console.log(patient)` does, check your `find()` function.

more info on `req.query` - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/express-js-req-query-property/

Comment: Please see here i attached my code and description what I actually want to get from there.
https://carbon.now.sh/K6IkDhsg7fH4WDUVre9K

Comment: what happens when you log for appointments before you use `res.send`?

Comment: It returns an empty array.

Comment: is there anything in your database?