# Why am I receiving a 404 when trying to render a page through node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, routes

I'm trying to use req.params to make my landing page dynamic after logging in. When I try to render the profile page, it says "404 Not Found". Here's my router:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


/* GET profile home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('profile', {name: req.params.name})
}); 

module.exports = router
```

And a portion of my app.js file;

```
var profileRouter = require('./app_server/routes/profile');

app.use('/profile', profileRouter);
```

Comment: You need add param , See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14508182/14741947)

Comment: Need more codes to understand your problem. I am using req.session.name to show the user's name in home page.