# GET request with parameter dosn't hiting desired route NODE js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, url-routing

The Problem occurs while sending **GET** or any request with parameters in the URL.

for example my
`index.js`

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/:name", function (req, res) {
    let name = req.params.name;
    console.log("Hello " + name + " from /:name");
    res.send("Hello " + name + " from /:name");
});
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    console.log("Hello world from /");
    res.send("Hello world from /");
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server is running on port " + 3000)
});
```

For `http://localhost:3000/` it's working perfectly fine.
[image: Home route "http://localhost:3000/"]

---

the Problem is occurring when we try to hit `/:name` route
when we use URL `http://localhost:3000/?name=NODE` it is going to the same route as above. in `/`

[image: Home route "http://localhost:3000/?"]

---

But the **crazy** part is when we put `http://localhost:3000/NODE` which is simply a new different route that is not implemented.
It is getting the response from `:/name` which doesn't make any sense.
[image]

---

**is it a BUG or I am doing something wrong or is it something new I am not aware of?**

I am currently using Windows11,
this problem also occurs in my friend's PC who uses Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define route as

```
/:name
```

That's called path parameter and it's used like this :

```
GET /yourname
```

And that's why this works :

```
GET /NODE
```

What you"re using to call the endpoint (?name=xxx) is called query parameter, you can get that name from '/' endpoint like this :

```
let name = req.query.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're *almost* there, but `/:name` does not match `/?name=`, but it *does* match `/NODE`.

This is exactly what's expected to happen. If this surprised you, go re-read the documentation because it should be pretty clear on this.

Comment: Ok I think I am confused between query parameter and params

Answer (score 0):

I think I am confused between query parameters and params.

Let:
given this URL `http://www.localhost:3000/NODE?a=Debasish&b=Biswas`

We will have:

req.**query**

```
{
  a: 'Debasish',
  b: 'Biswas'
}
```

req.**params**

```
{
  param1: 'NODE'
}
```

Here I am sending a query but want to receive params. That is where I go wrong.

For better understanding check :
[Node.js: Difference between req.query[] and req.params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417592/node-js-difference-between-req-query-and-req-params)

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#:~:text=)%0A%7D)-,Route%20parameters,-Route%20parameters%20are